# Is Gwent a good way of making money?

Tags: the-witcher-3

For the Gwent card game in *Witcher 3*, I notice that I can wager a bet when playing, such as betting 5 coins in the hopes of winning back 10 coins, therefore doubling my investment. I assume that there are other points where I can wager more than 10 coins, which is the most I've seen so far.

What's the most that I can wager in a single game, and where are the games played? Is it actually a reasonable way to make money, or are there faster ways?

Comment: Because its fun. otherwise don't.

Comment: Okay thanks. I understand it's there for fun, but there seem to also be investments made outside the card game, such as cards you can buy, to improve your chances of winning in the game, and I'm wondering how much of my money I should invest in cards, since it seems like it's hard to make money in the game.

Comment: later down the line there is a high stakes tournament that required a 1000 crowns to buy in, you can earn a significant sum of money here, however that's mostly due to the side quest that is triggered. Having a tough deck is essential as the opponents have great decks.

Comment: I tried joining that tournament and was turned away because my deck was too weak, so indeed you need a strong deck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't wager more than 10.

If I remember correctly, some NPC that can play gwent have a "high stakes" type of betting schema where you may potentially win more money. Usually these types of encounters happen via completing gwent quests.

Once your deck gets big enough and your level is high enough (like lvl ~25), you can compete in the "High Stakes" tournament (it's a quest) and win a lot of money... after you fight a group of thugs and other competitors. So yeah, don't do it before level 19 or 20.

As a side note, I think the best way to win money in Witcher 3 is to find treasure chests and complete witcher contracts.

Edit: Someone else pointed out that you have to pay 1000 up front to enter the High Stakes tournament. Absolutely true. You can't do it if you don't have the $$$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have blood and wine many npc's will bet for 50 which can net you 100 every win, not the best method but its consistant and reliable

Answer (score 1):

From my first play-through I cannot remember a single opponent where I could bet more than 100 coins. Many of the opponents where I could bet more than 10 coins I could only play against once. Those where I could play several times would only offer to bet at most 10 coins after I beat them the first time.

I found that there are more interesting ways to make money. Especially at higher levels just running around the map doing quests, killing bandits, wolves, and **selling loot at the right vendors**, gives significant amounts of money.

You can make a gwent deck where you reliably win more than 95% of the matches, so you can use gwent to make money. Just not more than while looting and questing.

Answer (score 1):

...to be more precise.  In general, every non-quest related game of Gwent that you play will be for between 1 - 10 coins.  However, while you are in Novigrad hunting for Whoreson Junior you will be sent to his casino.  Whilst inside you will have the option to play opponents for much higher amounts.  Outside of that as of 1.06, there are no "higher" stakes games available. Even in the High Stakes tournament you are only playing for the final leader cards from every faction. The individual matches reward a bit of XP, if I recall correctly, but no $$$. There is a final prize that you are contenting for, but as not to ruin the quest for anyone who hasn't done it, collecting your winnings gets... "complicated".